# ChromeOS can't install nodeJS

Tags: node.js, chromium

I followed this: https://gist.github.com/kalehv/5105268

But I have a problem :

> node: error while loading shared libraries: libhttp_parser.so.2.7.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I also tried to install the file "libhttp_parser.so.2.7.1" into /usr/lib/.

But it still will not work.

How can I fix this problem, or, is there some other way to install Node.js on Chrome OS.

I don't want to install on Crouton!

My Chrome OS version is 47.0.2526.106, unknown(64-bit).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you already switch your ChromeOS to dev mode?

Comment: Yes , I already